# About radiusclient command

Tags: linux, freeradius

I have installed freeradius server 2.1.12 and freeradius client 1.1.6 on different virtual machine (redhat linux) ,and tested the server using radtest which is  running . I have set up the connection between client and server and tested the connection using radlogin which is also running properly, but the problem is with command

```
[root@localhost ~]# radiusclient -f radiusclient.conf -p 1812 -a User-Name = testing -a Password = password -a Secret = testing123
error opening radius configuration file
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Or

```
[root@localhost ~]# radiusclient -f /etc/radiusclient/radiusclient.conf -p 1812 -a User-Name = testing -a Password = password -a Secret = testing123
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to check your radius server installation and configuration, it is enough to use any radius client such as `radtest` or `radclient`.

Do you need to test it specifically with `radiusclient`? I did not try this tool before. I think it will be a good idea to find an example on how to use it.

Comment: yes i want to use radiusclient command for testing.Is there anybody who can help me to solve this problem.It is urgent.

Comment: @Harman: What's the problem with other radius clients?

Comment: The problem is in opening of radiusclient.conf file while running command radiusclient -f radiusclient.conf -p 1812 -a User-Name = testing -a Password = password -a Secret = testing123

Comment: Did you check the file permissions?

Comment: yes ,i changed the file permission but the problem is still same

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command:

```
radiusclient -f /usr/local/etc/radiusclient/radiusclient.conf -p 1812 User-Name=steve Password=testing
```